# Call a secured EJB method on servlet on load(EAP 6.4)

Tags: security, ejb, jaas, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to call a secured EJB method on server load but I am getting exception:

```
09:49:58,011 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component SecuredEJB for method public java.lang.String org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.SecuredEJB.getSecurityInfo(): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public java.lang.String org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.SecuredEJB.getSecurityInfo() of bean: SecuredEJB is not allowed
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:114) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:86) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.SecuredEJB$$$view1.getSecurityInfo(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.SecuredEJBServlet.init(SecuredEJBServlet.java:55) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
```

My project structure is:

[image]

SecuredEJBServlet.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/SecuredEJBServlet")
@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = "quickstarts"))
public class SecuredEJBServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private SecuredEJB securedEJB;

    @Override
public void init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig arg0) throws javax.servlet.ServletException{
    Subject s = CMnJAASLogin.loginMethod();
    runAs(s);
    super.init(arg0);
    System.out.println("Inside init...");
    securedEJB.getName();
    //securedEJB.getSecurityInfo();
}

private void runAs(Subject s){
    Subject.doAs(s, new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object run() {
            System.out.println("Inside privileged action");
            securedEJB.getSecurityInfo();
            return null;
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        securedEJB.getName();
        String principal = securedEJB.getSecurityInfo();
...
}
```

SecuredEJB.java

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles("java")
@SecurityDomain("custom")
public class SecuredEJB {
    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @RolesAllowed({ "java" })
    public String getSecurityInfo() {
        Principal principal = ctx.getCallerPrincipal();
        return principal.toString();
    }

    @PermitAll
    public void getName(){
        System.out.println(principal.getName());
    }
}
```

CMnAuthenticator.java

```
public class CMnAuthenticator extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule{
    @Override
    protected String getUsersPassword() throws LoginException {
        return "java";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validatePassword(String passwordWant, String passwordHave){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Group[] getRoleSets() throws LoginException {
        HashMap setsMap = new HashMap();
        String groupName = "Roles";
        Group group = (Group) setsMap.get(groupName);
        if (group == null) {
            group = new SimpleGroup(groupName);
            setsMap.put(groupName, group);
        }
        try {
            Principal p = super.createIdentity("quickstarts");
            group.addMember(p);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Group[] roleSets = new Group[setsMap.size()];
        setsMap.values().toArray(roleSets);
        return roleSets;
    }
}
```

CMnEJBAuthenticator.java

```
public class CMnEJBAuthenticator extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule {
    @Override
    protected String getUsersPassword() throws LoginException {
        return "java";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validatePassword(String passwordWant, String passwordHave){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Group[] getRoleSets() throws LoginException {
        System.out.println("Inside CMnEJBAuthenticator:getRoleSets...");
        HashMap setsMap = new HashMap();
        String groupName = "Roles";
        Group group = (Group) setsMap.get(groupName);
        if (group == null) {
            group = new SimpleGroup(groupName);
            setsMap.put(groupName, group);
        }
        try {
            Principal p = super.createIdentity("java");
            group.addMember(p);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Group[] roleSets = new Group[setsMap.size()];
        setsMap.values().toArray(roleSets);
        return roleSets;
    }
}
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas
    http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_7_2.xsd">
    <!-- Configure usage of the security domain "other" -->
    <security-domain>servlet-security-quickstart</security-domain>
    <disable-audit>true</disable-audit>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   version="3.0">

   <!-- Configure login to be HTTP Basic -->
   <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>RealmUsersRoles</realm-name>
   </login-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>bootstrap</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.SecuredEJBServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>bootstrap</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

standalone.xml

```
<security-domain name="custom" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.others.CMnEJBAuthenticator" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="Super"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
<security-domain name="servlet-security-quickstart" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.others.CMnAuthenticator" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="Super"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

Jaas Authentication:

```
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.others;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CMnJAASLogin {

    public static Subject loginMethod(){
        LoginContext lc = null;

        CallbackHandler cabHndlr = new CallbackHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
                for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
                    if (callbacks[i] instanceof NameCallback) {
                        NameCallback nc = (NameCallback) callbacks[i];
                        nc.setName("java");
                    } else if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback) {
                        PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
                        pc.setPassword("java".toCharArray());
                    } else {
                        throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i], "Unrecognized Callback");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        try {
            lc = new LoginContext("custom", cabHndlr);
            lc.login();
            return lc.getSubject();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Note: I am working on JBoss EAP 6.4 and java 1.7

Adding @RunAs("java") to Servlet class solves this immediate problem.

But in case, i need to deny access for other users, RunAs annotation won't help there.

So, I am required to solve it in this way(if no user is calling the method/ejb/servlet, use "java" else use that users' role.

Comment: Added JAAS authentication but looks like SUbject.doAs is not working as expected. Edited the post/question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after using org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule in AppConfigurationProperty.

Finally, JAAS class looks like this:

```
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
import javax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;
import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CMnJAASLogin {

    public static LoginContext loginMethod() {
        LoginContext lc = null;

        CallbackHandler cabHndlr = new CallbackHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
                for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
                    if (callbacks[i] instanceof NameCallback) {
                        NameCallback nc = (NameCallback) callbacks[i];
                        nc.setName("java");
                    } else if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback) {
                        PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
                        pc.setPassword("java".toCharArray());
                    } else {
                        throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i], "Unrecognized Callback");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        try {
            String configurationName = "JBoss Test";
            Configuration config = new JBossJaasConfiguration(configurationName);

            lc = new LoginContext(configurationName, new Subject(), cabHndlr, config);
            return lc;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    static class JBossJaasConfiguration extends Configuration {
        private final String configurationName;

        JBossJaasConfiguration(String configurationName) {
            this.configurationName = configurationName;
        }

        @Override
        public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
            if (!configurationName.equals(name)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected configuration name '" + name + "'");
            }

            return new AppConfigurationEntry[]{

                    createClientLoginModuleConfigEntry(),

            };
        }

        private AppConfigurationEntry createClientLoginModuleConfigEntry() {
            Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
            options.put("multi-threaded", "true");
            options.put("restore-login-identity", "true");

            return new AppConfigurationEntry("org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule",
                    AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, options);
        }
    }
}
```

Whole project is uploaded to: https://github.com/shekharswaraj/EJBSecurity

NOTE: It is just a test project with many hard coded values. The whole project has been modified on top of ejb-security project from EAP6.4 quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but §15.3.1 of the servlet spec says that you just need to add a `run-as` element to your servlet definition in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>bootstrap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb_security.SecuredEJBServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <run-as>java</run-as>
</servlet>
```

However, it is not completely clear whether or not the actual authenticated principal will be propagated to the EJBs for the normally authenticated servlet calls. You will have to try it and see.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for the comment. I tried it but it did not work. <run-as>
            <role-name>java</role-name>
        </run-as> and I am getting same exception.

Comment: Yes - it seems that it is a Servlet 3.1 thing. Consider testing it on WildFly 10.1 and if that is an improvement you may need to move to JBoss EAP 7.x

Comment: @RunAs("java") to SecuredEJBServlet.java solves this problem.

Comment: I will delete this answer as I don't think it's useful for anyone

Comment: At least it is one of the many things to try. I think, u can leave it as is.